# bobj system tables

Tags: data-warehouse, business-objects, system-tables

I am new to BOBJ reporting and I am trying to generate a data dictioanry for BOBJ reports , like what universe does a report look into, what object does a report column refer and what tabel in the DB does this report column inturn refer.. such kind of information.

Is there any system tables present in BOBJ like `all_tab_cols`,`all_tables` etc in Oracle or `rep_all_mappings`, `rep_mapping_conn_ports` in informatica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to do this through querying the BO repository database.  The reason is that the database contents are *encrypted*.  The only way I know of going about something similar would be to use the various SDKs to first "query" the InfoStore for the relationships between the report objects, Universe objects and connection objects.

As for where various Universe objects map to database entries, that requires SDK work to walk through the actual Universe to create the required results.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give Query Builder a shot. This allows you to query the underlying database. Unlike the pre XI versions where the data repository could be mapped to a queryable universe the newer version of the CMS repository does not lend itself to a simple universe mapping.